# Magento 2 product listing page quantity increment decrement button

Tags: magento2

I am trying to make quantity increment plus minus button on product listing page for magento 2. I have see php cuong made a good module but that only works on details page. How I can add functionality on listing page.

Comment: kindly check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to your **list.phtml** before the "**Add to Cart**" button.

```
<div class="field qty">
    <div class="control qty-change">
        <?php $id = "qty_".$_product->getId(); ?>
        <button  type="button" class="reduced items" onclick="var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 1 ) result.value--;return false;">-</button>
        <input type="text"
               name="qty"
               id="<?= $id ?>"
               value="1"
               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
               />
        <button  type="button" class="increase items" onclick="var result = document.getElementById('<?= $id ?>'); var qty = result.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) result.value++;return false;">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Hope this will work for you.